# How to calculate magnitude of frequency response?

Tags: filters, fourier-transform, python, finite-impulse-response

I'm trying to write a function in Python that calculates the magnitude of an FIR filters frequency response. I tried doing it by first calculating the Fourier transform with np.fft.fft and then calculating the absolute value with Pythons abs function. It looks something like this:

```
def freqresponse(X,N):
  h = np.fft.fft(X)
  h_db = 20*np.log10(abs(h))
  return h_db
```

The input parameter X are the filter coefficient vector from the specific filter you want to calculate. Ex: a lowpass filter. Not sure if this is the right way to do it since I also want the parameter "N" to be the number of frequencies in the range  ω between 0 and . My question is how do I specify the range N as well and if it really is the right move to use fourier transform in this case? I could really use some guidance, thankful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! Just do `np.fft.fft(X,N)` with `N`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Python directly using 'scipy.signal.freqz' as

```
import signal.scipy as sig
w,h = sig.freqz(X)
```

and plot with matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot(w, abs(h))
```

(more often you convert h to dB with a $20Log_{10}()$ operation). This shows the minimum needed to create the frequency response. `freqz` has many more optional parameters allowing for IIR filters, increased number of samples, etc. Review `help(freqz)` for more info.

`freqz` will compute samples on the Discrete Time Fourier Transform (DTFT), and you can accomplish a similar result with zero-padding the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) as follows:

```
def freqresponse(X, N=512):
  h = np.fft.fft(X, N)
  h_db = 20*np.log10(abs(h))
  return h_db
```

Comment: `freqz` also takes a parameter for `N`, otherwise it’s 512, I think.